# Discord.js How to send a message into a channel after bots turns on

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make my bot say something in my Staff chat when it turns on, but i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.channels.cache.get("channel ID here").send("Hello, I just started");
});
```